# How to use lookup on two collection having object property of variable size

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have two collections one is `company` and other is `reports` so below is my company collection.

**company collection**

```
[
 {
  company_id:1,
  hubId:4
  dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'USA'},
  name:'Amsol Inc.'
 },
 {
   company_id:1,
   hubId:4
   dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'Canada'},
   name:'Amsol Inc.'
 },
 {
   company_id:2,
   hubId:7
   dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'USA',revenue:34555},
   name:'Microsoft Inc.'
 }
]
```

**reports collection**

```
[
 {
  report_id:1,
  name:'example report',
  hubId:4
  dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'USA'},
  name:'Amsol Inc.'
 },
 {
   report_id:2,
   name:'example report',
   hubId:4
   dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'Canada'},
   name:'Amsol Inc.'
 },
 {
   report_id:3,
   name:'example report',
   hubId:5
   dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'USA',revenue:20000},
   name:'Microsoft Inc.'
 }
 {
   report_id:4,
   name:'example report',
   hubId:4
   dimensions:{region:'North america',country:'Greenland'},
   name:'Amsol Inc.'
 },
]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 [
  {
  report_id:1,
  name:'example report',
  hubId:4
  dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'USA'},
  name:'Amsol Inc.'
 },
 {
   report_id:2,
   name:'example report',
   hubId:4,
   dimensions:{region:'North america',country:'Canada'},
   name:'Amsol Inc.'
 }
]
```

I want to fetch all the report that has same `HubId` and `dimensions` as of companies.

For Ex: `hubId = 4` has 2 companies in `company` collection but they have different dimensions So here I want to search for all the reports having `hubId = 4` and dimensions like matches with any of these companies.

If you noticed, the collections have thousands of records like this.

I have been looking for some aggregation pipeline but fail to understand how can I apply the logic here to get the result here.

Comment: so the goal is to return two entries, 1 for each company, where each entry has all the reports for that company's dimenisons?

Comment: No not like that its like if you noticed company collection have same hubId but dimensions values are different so I want to filter as mamy records in reports collection which matches this `hubId` and `dimensions` having similar to these companies in company collection there can be multiple companies like that having same `hubId` but different `dimensions`.So here i want to make a search based on hubId and dimensions  in report collection but dimensions values can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, a `$lookup` with pipeline can do the job:
The `let` defines the arguments from the `reports` collection, and they are used with `$$` inside the `$lookup` pipeline. The `$` arguments are for the context of the `$lookup` pipeline, meaning the `company` collection.

The `$setEquals` is used to test equality of arrays where the order of items is not important. Here it is used with `$objectToArray` to test equality of objects (which are being changed to arrays and then compared).

```
db.reports.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "company",
      let: {hubId: "$hubId", dimensions: "$dimensions"},      
      as: "companies",
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {$eq: ["$hubId", "$$hubId"]},
                {$setEquals: [
                    {$objectToArray: "$dimensions"},
                    {$objectToArray: "$$dimensions"}
                ]}
              ]
            }
        }},
        {$project: {_id: 1}}
      ]
  }},
  {$match: {"companies.0": {$exists: true}}},
  {$unset: "companies"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_PeVhj2Rj-c)

Comment: But here dimensions key are changing its not fixed if we changed the hubId to 5 then we have three fileds in dimensions object.HOw do we get know.

Comment: Your answer is correct and giving desired result but my concern is what I commented above.

Comment: Updated the answer according to your comment

Comment: what is $$ means which u did in `$setEquals: [
                    {
                      "$objectToArray": "$dimensions"
                    },
                    {
                      "$objectToArray": "$$dimensions"
                    }
                  ]`

Comment: what this logic does can you please tell.

Comment: Updated the answer to include elaboration

Comment: Got it one last thing `{$match: {"companies.0": {$exists: true}}}` here what does companies.0 means

Comment: It means that there is an item inside the` companies` array, in our case, meaning there is a matching company

Comment: To me this is giving error might be because of in some documents i have dimensions filed is null for both collections or any one of the collections.How can I handle null vaules here.

Comment: I checked for `$ifnull` operator bjt should i place in above pipeline.

Comment: One option is like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3IIqIvACUUK). If you have another case please include an example and the wanted result from it

Comment: I simply changed the names with my real collections and fields are same as given in your solution but failed to get desired result getting empty companies array.

Comment: I got the issue i have `hub_id` in `company` collection is in string and in `report` its in integer type.How to convert hub_id in company to integer.

Comment: Use [`$toInt`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/)

Comment: Can I pass value that I get in query string in place of `$hubId` and `$dimensions` in let.

Comment: If I can narrow down lookup by applying match criteria before lookup suppose where `hubId=5` then response would be faster.

Comment: Yes, you can. Try and see

Comment: Hi bro, I have posted one question its same as above but have little change can you please look into it [see question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75005921/how-to-ignore-fields-from-one-object-during-comparison-with-another-object-in-mo)