# How to ignore fields from one object during comparison with another object in MongoDb aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation

I have two collections one is company and other is reports so below is my company collection.

**company collection**

```
 [
  {
   company_id:1,
   hubId:4
   dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'USA',distribution:'all',sub-distribution:'all'},
   name:'Amsol Inc.'
  },
  {
   company_id:1,
   hubId:4
   dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'Canada'},
   name:'Amsol Inc.'
  },
  {
   company_id:2,
   hubId:7
   dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'USA',revenue:34555},
   name:'Microsoft Inc.'
  }
 ]
```

**reports collection**

```
 [
  {
   report_id:1,
   name:'example report',
   hubId:4
   dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'USA'},
   name:'Amsol Inc.'
  },
  {
   report_id:2,
   name:'example report',
   hubId:4
   dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'Canada'},
   name:'Amsol Inc.'
  },
  {
   report_id:3,
   name:'example report',
   hubId:5
   dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'USA',revenue:20000},
   name:'Microsoft Inc.'
  }
  {
   report_id:4,
   name:'example report',
   hubId:4
   dimensions:{region:'North america',country:'Greenland'},
   name:'Amsol Inc.'
 },
]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[
 {
  report_id:1,
  name:'example report',
  hubId:4
  dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'USA'},
  name:'Amsol Inc.'
 },
 {
  report_id:2,
  name:'example report',
  hubId:4,
  dimensions:{region:'North america',country:'Canada'},
  name:'Amsol Inc.'
 }
]
```

I want to fetch all the report that has same `HubId` and `dimensions` as of companies.But in `company` collection in dimension field few documents have properties `distribution` and `sub-distribution`so during comparison of dimensions of both the collections I want to ignore these 2 fields from `dimensions` object of reports collection included in all the documents.

Below is my aggregation pipeline:

```
db.reports.aggregate([
{$lookup: {
  from: "company",
  let: {hubId: "$hubId", dimensions: "$dimensions"},      
  as: "companies",
  pipeline: [
    {$match: {
        $expr: {
          $and: [
            {$eq: ["$hubId", "$$hubId"]},
            {$setEquals: [
                {$objectToArray: "$dimensions"},
                {$objectToArray: "$$dimensions"}
            ]}
          ]
        }
    }},
    {$project: {_id: 1}}
    ]
  }},
])
```

Here what change do I make in order to get the desired result.Anyone let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add `$filter`:

```
db.reports.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "company",
      let: {
        hubId: "$hubId",
        dimensions: "$dimensions"
      },
      as: "companies",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$hubId",
                    "$$hubId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $setEquals: [
                    {
                      $filter: {
                        input: {
                          $objectToArray: "$dimensions"
                        },
                        as: "compKey",
                        cond: {
                          $not: {
                            $in: [
                              "$$compKey.k",
                              [
                                "sub-distribution",
                                "distribution"
                              ]
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      $objectToArray: "$$dimensions"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IjUlcPhvsom)

Comment: What is `$$compKey.k`

Comment: `$$compKey.k` is a reference to a key in the `$dimensions` object. The object is transformed to array with `{k, v}` pairs. `$$compKey` is the temporal reference to this object and `$$compKey.k` is the temporal reference to the name of the key

Comment: What if one of the field in  `dimensions` object  in `company` collection.Let's say `country` is of type `Array` like `country:['USA','CANADA']` only in one collection then above  dimension comparison would work.

Comment: Hi I have some doubt can You please look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75054288/how-to-compare-two-objects-in-which-one-having-arrayf-ield-using-mongodb-aggrega)

Comment: This answer is for this question. Your link is leading to a new and different question. I recommend you to structure your db in a more unified way.

Comment: Actually I am working on the existing db which has thousands of records and data is unstructured that's why causing issues.

Comment: Yeah I need help for that new question that I have posted recently.