# How to compare two objects in which one having array field using MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation

I have two collections one is `company` and other is `reports`. Below are my collections.

**company collection**

```
[
 {
  company_id:1,
  hubId:4
  dimensions:{ region:['North america'],country:['USA']},
  name:'Amsol Inc.'
 },
 {
  company_id:1,
  hubId:4
  dimensions:{ region:['North america'],country:['Canada','Greenland']},
  name:'Amsol Inc.'
 },
 {
  company_id:2,
  hubId:7
  dimensions:{ region:['North america'],country:['USA'],revenue:34555},
  name:'Microsoft Inc.'
 }
]
```

**reports collection**

```
   [
    {
     report_id:1,
     name:'example report',
     hubId:4
     dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'USA'},
     name:'Amsol Inc.'
    },
    {
     report_id:2,
     name:'example report',
     hubId:4
     dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'Canada'},
     name:'Amsol Inc.'
    },
    {
     report_id:3,
     name:'example report',
     hubId:5
     dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'USA',revenue:20000},
     name:'Microsoft Inc.'
    }
    {
     report_id:4,
     name:'example report',
     hubId:4
     dimensions:{region:'North america',country:'Greenland'},
     name:'Amsol Inc.'
    }
   ]
```

**Output**

```
   [
    {
     report_id:1,
     name:'example report',
     hubId:4
     dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'USA'},
     name:'Amsol Inc.'
    },
    {
     report_id:2,
     name:'example report',
     hubId:4,
     dimensions:{region:'North america',country:'Canada'},
     name:'Amsol Inc.'
    },
    {
     report_id:4,
     name:'example report',
     hubId:4
     dimensions:{region:'North america',country:'Greenland'},
     name:'Amsol Inc.'
    }
   ]
```

I want to fetch all the report that has same `HubId` and `dimensions` as of companies. But in company collection in dimension field region and country fields are array and in reports collection they both are string. How can I get the desired output?

I tried checking by `$ObjectToArray` operator in MongoDB pipeline but it's not working. It's showing one result which is completely matching its ignoring array elements.

Below is my aggregation pipeline I tried:

```
 db.reports.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
             from: "company",
             let: {hubId: "$hubId", dimensions: "$dimensions"},      
             as: "companies",
             pipeline: [
                {$match: {
                  $expr: {
                         $and: [
                                {$eq: ["$hubId", "$$hubId"]},
                                {$setEquals: [
                                              {$objectToArray: "$dimensions"},
                                              {$objectToArray: "$$dimensions"}
                                ]}
                        ]
            }
        }},
           {$project: {_id: 1}}
      ]
    }},
  ])
```

How can I get the desired result while comparing array and string elements inside an object?

Comment: I not sure what you try to achieve, but from `company` collection: `dimensions:{ region:['North america'],country:['USA']}` and `reports` collection: `dimensions:{ region:'North america',country:'USA'}`, there is no match.

Comment: Is this something that you want to achieve? [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VXrolznzxDv)

Comment: In companies collection for `company_id:2` I missed earlier making region and country field to array that time it was showing correct results but after I updated my company collection its not showing desired result.It should include `report_id:4` also in a result.

Comment: Can you try once with the updated `company` collection.

Comment: Suspect that compares the objects with `$eq` is not recommended as the order of keys matters. Possibly this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t7SNgOfZSKu) is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way...

```
db.reports.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "company",
      let: {
        hubId: "$hubId",
        dimensionsCountry: "$dimensions.country",
        dimensionsRegion: "$dimensions.region"
      },
      as: "companies",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: ["$hubId","$$hubId"]
                },
                {
                  $in: ["$$dimensionsRegion","$dimensions.region"]
                },
                {
                  $in: ["$$dimensionsCountry","$dimensions.country"]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {"_id": 1}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {$size: "$companies"}, 0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uRL__WSVDMi)